# Change Tableau custom SQL query to reflect year instead of number

Tags: sql, tableau-api

**Custom SQL query**
--Why does year come out as a number with sum parameter

```
select
YEAR(s.OrderDate) 'Year',
cat.EnglishProductCategoryName 'Category',
sub.EnglishProductSubcategoryName 'Subcategory',

Count(1) 'Count',
sum (s.SalesAmount) 'Sales',
avg (s.SalesAmount) 'Avg_Sales_Amt',
min (s.SalesAmount) 'Min_Sales_Amt',
max (s.SalesAmount) 'Max_Sales_Amt'
```

[Table output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kughk.png)

Comment: Your question is confusing.  Why _wouldn't_ the year be a number?  But in the output you linked it appears that there is a comma appearing in the year.  Maybe this is just a formatting issue.  Also, you did not show us your entire query.

Comment: it is usually better to avoid custom sql unless you have a specialized need when working with tableau. For most connections, you get more flexibility and better performance by specifying the tables, views or specifying joins and unions in the connection pane. Otherwise you prevent some query optimizations and have to edit the custom sql whenever there is any change to a table, even just a new column.

Answer (score 0):

Why - as Tableau recognises it as a number and converts it to that format.

You can just change Year to Dimension instead a Measure and change the data type to String instead of changing the Custom SQL.